# Modifying Laravel’s Generated Registration Logic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

So, I am still kind of a newbie to Laravel.  As part of the application I am working on, I want to modify the registration logic generated by

```
php artisan make:auth
```

to add e-mail verification for newly registered users.

I modify the create() method on the generated RegisterController to look like this.

```
 protected function create(array   $data)
  {
      $user = User::create([

        'name' => $data['name'],

        'email' => $data['email'],

        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    // generate and store verification token

    $token = new Token; 
    $token->user_id = $user->id; 
    $token->token = str_randome(40); 
    $token->save(); 
    // send a verification e-mail to the 
    $this->sendVerificationEmail($user->id); 

    return $user;
}
```

So, on to my question. Suppose I want to capture the returned user on the verification page (which is assigned to the $redirectTo property) so that the application knows to which user to resend the e-mail if said user requests it be resent. What is the best way to achieve this?

Should I just create a new route like this

```
 // Routes/web.php

Route::post(‘register/{$user}’, ‘RegisterController@showConfirmation’);
```

And then in my RegisterController

```
// RegisterController
public function showConfirmation($user)
{ return view(“accountConfirmation”)->([“user”=> $user]);}
```

Or is there another way? I guess the route of my problem here is that I don’t quite yet understand how Laravel performs this process. But, anyways.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create another route but make it secure by either hash or encrypt the user data you are passing in the url or confirm the url parameter two times with different logic
Or you can simply pass the user from one method to another in the controller
`$this->showConfirmation( $user )` from your `create()` method